# Expected Iterable but did not find one for field

Tags: javascript, sqlite, graphql

Using GraphQL and SQLite, this is my query:

```
{
book {
  id
  authors {
    name
  }
 }
}
```

The types:

```
  type Book {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    actors: [Author!]!
  }
  type Author {
    id: ID!
    name: String
  }
```

And this is my resolve:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
        book: async (_, __, { db }) => {
      return await db.all('SELECT * FROM books');
    },
  }
};
```

The error is:

> "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field
>   Book.authors.",

Answer (score 0):

In your query resolver you are only resolving `books` from your select `'SELECT * FROM books'`.

If you want to be able to query `books` and `authors`, and have only one resolver, you have to return both objects, i.e. you have to build and return the full object in your resolver `book`.